# Inline css for making a wordpress theme

Tags: php, css, wordpress, themes

I am creating a wordpress theme and all the css is working fine. However I implemented a bootstrap jumbotron slider where basically I have 3 divs and each div has an inline style in the index.php file with it's own background image.However, my wordpress theme does not recognize any styles that I implement straight into index.php
Any solutions or work arounds?

Comment: Why do you need to use inline CSS? As well as causing you the difficulties you're having here, its better practice and easier to maintain if you use an external stylesheet (or even an internal style tag if you must)

Answer (score 0):

WordPress by default strips out any code that may be considered "code" or malicious. Yet, there are ways to add inline code to a WordPress without WordPress Plugins to overwrite the default functionality of WordPress. For example, As you didn't provided any code, so here is just an example.

```
<h2>Header</h2>
```

Here is how you can do it with inline css

```
<h2 style="color:red;">Header</h2>
```

The issue with Inline CSS is it’s really only used for one-off occasions! You would never really use this to apply a consistent feel across all your pages.

P.S This is most important, don't forget to include your `bootstrap.min.css` file in your wordpress `function.php`

Comment: My bootstrap is included in functions.php and it's working perfectly fine.. I just need 3 inline styles on the divs to make the slider work.

Comment: why use inline? u can add ur style to `style.css` and use the class name on slider, it will work as usual